# Eclipse IDE is catching an error in main however main itself has no issues?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, program-entry-point, throws

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKE4t.png]]

```
I have no code in my main method, or any separate classes. I'm still getting errors.
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
```

```
However the debugger say main() is throwing Error(id=23)
===========================================================
  Unresolved compilation problem: Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: is that java.awt.Canvas?

Comment: Ya, I removed it, but I still had the same issue. I was trying to include files in my build path, but I did it wrong. I found this out through the problems section on the eclipse IDE. Apparently, there is more definitive information than in the console or the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there make sure you check the problems tab next to the console tab. I had a build path error. I was selecting an invalid library. So the debugger just throws some random error.

Comment: Your application (not the debugger) throws "Unresolved compilation problem" for the executed code that cannot be compiled (the Eclipse compiler for Java is able to create bytecode for classes even when there are compile errors in some parts).

Comment: Wouldn't this be good for people to see maybe they made the same mistake?

Comment: I feel like most people don't realize the console isn't the only thing that feeds you debug information, but there is a separate area called the problems tab.